# Aggregate Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this:

[image]

I would like to aggregate the table like this:

[image]

Explanation:

For Yes to increment: need just 1 yes across grouped response by user for each item. In above example, At least one result for Item_1 for user 1 and 2 is Yes. So "Yes" is 2(1+1). One for each user.

For No to increment: need all no’s across grouped response by user for each item. In above example, All the result for Item_2 is "No" for User 1.So "No" is 1.

For N/A to increment: need all N/A’s across grouped response by user for each item. In above example, all the result for Item_2 is "N/A" for User 2. So "N/A" is again 1.

Notes:

There are just 2 items Item_1 and Item_2

Result is either Yes, No or N/A

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use [Pivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Case statements would be vastly easier than a pivot, in this case.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew: you have 2 items and 3 results, that gives 6 possibilities. CASE statement is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have tweaked the solution by GarethD to now correctly account for cases where there is no 'Yes' and not all 'No' or 'N/A':

```
SELECT  Item,
        Yes = COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 'Yes' THEN 1 END),
        [No] = COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 'No' THEN 1 END),
        [N/A] = COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 'N/A' THEN 1 END),
        Unique_User_Count = COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)
FROM    (   SELECT  UserID, 
                    Item, 
                    Result = MAX(Result)
            FROM    UserResult
            GROUP BY UserID, Item
            HAVING MAX(Result) = MIN(Result)
            OR MAX(Result) = 'Yes'
        ) AS T
GROUP BY Item;
```

This is my original solution, which I knew could be shorter:

```
WITH yes AS
(
    SELECT Item_ID, User_ID
    FROM table1 
    WHERE Result = 'Yes'
    GROUP BY User_ID,Item_ID
), no AS
(
    SELECT Item_ID, User_ID
    FROM table1 t0
    WHERE NOT EXIST
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM table1
        WHERE Result != 'No'
        AND Item_ID = t0.Item_ID
        AND User_ID = t0.User_ID)
    )
    GROUP BY Item_ID, User_ID
), na AS
(
    SELECT Item_ID, User_ID
    FROM table1 t0
    WHERE NOT EXIST
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM table1
        WHERE Result != 'N/A'
        AND Item_ID = t0.Item_ID
        AND User_ID = t0.User_ID)
    )
    GROUP BY Item_ID, User_ID
)
SELECT
    t1.Item_ID,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM yes
        GROUP BY Item_ID
        WHERE Item_ID = t1.Item_ID
    ) AS yes,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM no
        GROUP BY Item_ID
        WHERE Item_ID = t1.Item_ID
    ) AS no,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM na
        GROUP BY Item_ID
        WHERE Item_ID = t1.Item_ID
    ) AS na,   
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID)
        FROM table1
        WHERE Item_ID = t1.Item_ID
    ) AS Unique_User_Count
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.Item_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

To get down to one response per user you can use:

```
SELECT  UserID, 
        Item_Name, 
        Result = MAX(Result)
FROM    T
GROUP BY UserID, Item_Name
```

This simply takes advantage of the fact that in descending order the available values are Yes, No, N/A, so using `MAX` will mean that if a user has a result of yes this will be picked, if not and the result of no exists, this will be used, otherwise it will be N/A

Then you can use a conditional aggregate:

```
SELECT  Item_Name,
        Yes = COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 'Yes' THEN 1 END),
        [No] = COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 'No' THEN 1 END),
        [N/A] = COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 'N/A' THEN 1 END),
        Unique_User_Count = COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)
FROM    (   SELECT  UserID, 
                    Item_Name, 
                    Result = MAX(Result)
            FROM    T
            GROUP BY UserID, Item_Name
        ) AS T
GROUP BY Item_Name;
```

Comment: Pretty clever solution

Comment: I llike the solution but it will not return correct 'No' count if there is no 'Yes'. Please see the fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66cef/3 . I am still receiving No for Item_1 even if there is no all "No" across grouped response

Comment: Thanks GarethD. This helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can just use case statements with counts:

```
    select
    Item_Name,
    count (Case when result = 'Yes' then 1 else null end) as "Yes",
    count (case when result = 'No' then 1 else null end) as "No"...
group by item_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is from popovitsj. There are minor typos in the original solution but the solution from GarethD and updates by popovitsj is more elegant.  Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab5e7/1

```
create table #UserResult
(
 UserID int,
 Item varchar(50),
 Result varchar(50))

 insert into #UserResult values(1,'Item_1','No')
 insert into #UserResult values(1,'Item_1','No')
 insert into #UserResult values(1,'Item_1','No')
 insert into #UserResult values(1,'Item_1','Yes')

 insert into #UserResult values(1,'Item_2','No')
 insert into #UserResult values(1,'Item_2','No')

 insert into #UserResult values(2,'Item_1','Yes')
 insert into #UserResult values(2,'Item_1','No')

 insert into #UserResult values(2,'Item_2','N/A')
 insert into #UserResult values(2,'Item_2','N/A')

 select * from #UserResult

;WITH yes AS
 (
     SELECT Item, UserID
     FROM #UserResult 
    WHERE Result = 'Yes'
    GROUP BY UserID,Item
 ),no AS
(
    SELECT Item, UserID
    FROM #UserResult t0
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM #UserResult
    WHERE Result != 'No'
    AND Item = t0.Item
    AND UserID = t0.UserID
)
GROUP BY Item, UserID
),na AS
(
    SELECT Item, UserID
    FROM #UserResult t0
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM #UserResult
    WHERE Result != 'N/A'
    AND Item = t0.Item
    AND UserID = t0.UserID
)
GROUP BY Item, UserID
)

select t1.Item,

(
   select COUNT(*) from yes  where Item=t1.Item group by Item
) as Yes,
(
   select COUNT(*) from no  where Item=t1.Item group by Item
 ) as No,
(
   select COUNT(*) from na  where Item=t1.Item group by Item
) as Na


from #UserResult t1 
 group by t1.Item

 drop table #UserResult
```

Comment: Hey, I deleted it because I thought the solution by GarethD was superior. I undeleted it now.